# How can i acces User details?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to access the User details. `devise` already creates an email and password for the user when he or she signs up. I now, for example, would like to see the address of the current user in my view (on the page). My schema has been added below. I already tried `<%= current_user.email %>` but that's not working.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_10_22_183225) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "positions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "tripnumber"
    t.string "activity"
    t.string "date"
    t.string "time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "barge_name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user (instance of `User`) should be accessible via `current_user` in controllers and their views once you setup devise correctly and have the user signed in. If `current_user` is `nil` it means that user have not logged in yet.

Devise works on top of warden middleware and relies on session for authenticating users, check if cookies are being set. Also if you have just added devise - restart your server so that middleware gets picked up (and spring via `spring stop`, just to be sure)

Comment: oke so you think it could be because i am not logged in, for example now i receive this error. undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #4):
 
<h1><%= current_user.email %></h1>

Comment: @skosman that’s exactly the error you would get if `current_user` is `nil`

Comment: i think you are right, but that brings me to the next issue, when i log in, the page stays on the login page, the page it should route me to has to be authenticated with a password, when i do that nothing happens ... can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

It seems devise is not configured correctly. You should re-check [the guide line](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

below my the app controller and routes, normally when i open localhost:3000 its show me the positions/new page, now i get redirected to the login page which is good, but after logging in it does nothing ....

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end

routes:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root to: 'positions#new'

resources :positions


end
```